# bootstrap dropdown choose confirm by button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

after selecting the item from dropdown the user will confirm the selection by clicking the button. and then has to move it to the page assigned to this item how to do it? after selecting the item from dropdown the user will confirm the selection by clicking the button. and then has to move it to the page assigned to this item how to do it?

thanks :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap-select Tests (Bootstrap 4)</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

  <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <select class="selectpicker" data-width="75%" data-live-search="true" title="Wybierz urządzenie...">
    <optgroup label="Producent1">
      <option><a href="#">Maszyna 1</a></option>
      <option>Maszyna 2</option>
      <option>Maszyna 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Producent1">
      <option>Maszyna 1</option>
      <option>Maszyna 2</option>
      <option>Maszyna 3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <button type="button" data-width="75%" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Szukaj!</button>

  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:
 html file:

```html
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectedItem"> select:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectedItem" name="selectedItem">
            <optgroup label="Producent1">
                <option value="Maszyna1">Maszyna 1</option>
                <option value="Maszyna2">Maszyna 2</option>
                <option value="Maszyna3">Maszyna 3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Producent2">
                <option value="Maszyna4">Maszyna 4</option>
                <option value="Maszyna5">Maszyna 5</option>
                <option value="Maszyna6">Maszyna 6</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="btnRedirect" data-width="75%" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Szukaj!</button>
</form>
```

page.php file:

```php
<?php
$addresses=array(
'Maszyna1'=>'https://facebook.com',
'Maszyna2'=>'https://google.com',
'Maszyna3'=>'https://twitter.com/',
);
if (isset($_POST['selectedItem']) && !empty($_POST['selectedItem'])){
  $selectedItem=$_POST['selectedItem'];
 foreach ($addresses as $key=> $address){
     if ($selectedItem===$key)
         header("Location:".$address);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: this is what I mean, but in dropdown I will have a lot of items, and I do not hide that in php where I would have a variable and links to it it would be more convenient to supplement it, and otherwise it would not be possible to see the content of php. can you do it in php?

Comment: of course, there will be many entries in the dropdown, but a few of them will be with the same id, I mean - so that I can complete the links from the php file and not the whole code

Comment: again. I have a dropdown list with id, for example "Maszyna1" or "Maszyna2" and so on. I want it to be moved to a specific page after selecting one option and confirming with the button, but these pages are defined in a separate file, it can be a telsts file, xls or php file in which I will have, for example, Maszyna1: 'http://facebook.com' or for Maszyna2 - google.com. I want these links to dropdown choices to be in a different file than in the whole code

Comment: I changed my answer. please check it.

Comment: yes!!!!! thats what i needed. it will be perfectly if i can have a 'Maszyna1'=>'https://facebook.com',
'Maszyna2'=>'https://google.com',
'Maszyna3'=>'https://twitter.com/', -> in txt file/ nut if not, it still perfect!! think about txt please

Comment: So, Did your question finish about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

put it in form tag with action and method attributes and change button type to submit. a something like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectedItem"> select:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectedItem" name="selectedItem">
            <optgroup label="Producent1">
                <option value="https://www.facebook.com/">Maszyna 1</option>
                <option value="https://www.google.com/">Maszyna 2</option>
                <option value="Maszyna3">Maszyna 3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Producent2">
                <option value="Maszyna3">Maszyna 3</option>
                <option value="Maszyna4">Maszyna 4</option>
                <option value="Maszyna5">Maszyna 5</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" data-width="75%" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Szukaj!</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to do that? for example - add a id into a <option> and how to find this id in page.php with correct link and load it?

Comment: after submit, you can get selected item by S_POST['selectedItem'] in PHP.

Comment: i dont know how to do that. could you write to me and paste here? im trying and i still dont know :(

Comment: create page.php file  and put this code: <?php echo $_POST['selectedItem'];

Comment: it something went wrong. if i click a "Maszyna 1" and submit it will show for me a https://facebook.com ; but if i choose a "Maszyna 2" i would see a https://google.com

Comment: please, write for me a content of page.php, i dont know how :(

Comment: I couldn't understand, Do you want to earn selected option value or redirect the user to some web sites?  my code sends an item that user will select and in the page.php file shows.

Comment: after selecting the option I want to redirect the user to a specific page. please help